# PHP XSS Prevention WhiteListing

Tags: php, validation, xss, wysiwyg

My site utilizes a WYSIWYG editor for users to update their accounts,enter comments, and send private messages.

The editor (CKEditor) is great for only allowing users to enter valid input, but I worry about injection through TamperData or other means.

How can I control this on the server side?

I need to whitelist specific tags: `<b><ul><ol><a><img><br>`, will this be a SAFE approach to preventing XSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)**:

> HTML Purifier is a standards-compliant
>   HTML filter library written in PHP.
>   HTML Purifier will not only remove all
>   malicious code (better known as XSS)
>   with a thoroughly audited, secure yet
>   permissive whitelist.

Comment: Is there an advantage of doing this over strip_tags with my own white-list?

Comment: Actually, I found my answer here: http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

strip_tags is going to be your friend.  The second parameter lets you pass in an array of allowed tags
[strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Comment: The second parameter **is unsafe**, because it doesn't remove attributes. Someone can still exploit attributes on safe element, e.g. `<br style="(stretch to full screen)" onmouseover="evil_script()">`.

Comment: How do you purpose that person will inject the code for evil_script ?