# How can I safely output content that contains HTML tags?

Tags: php, html

I have a blog system, and the user has to input content into an html text area, including html tags such as `<p>`. This is stored in a database. If this input is then echoed to a web page using php, how can I escape the output to protect against XSS, but preserve the meaning of the html tags, so that the blog post is formatted correctly? If I use `htmlentities($blog_content)` it literally prints the html tags to the page, so you see `<p>hello this is a blog</p>`.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you tested htmlentities() ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP XSS Prevention WhiteListing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992674/php-xss-prevention-whitelisting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is selective filtering or sanitization. In other words, you want to allow *some* HTML, but not other, possibly malicious tags. This is very tricky business, especially since HTML syntax is very complex and overly simple sanitization attempts are prone to errors which allow injection of tags through malformed HTML anyway.

If possible, you should stay away from letting your users submit HTML at all. Use a special markup language like Wiki markup, Markdown, BBcodes or similar.

If you are sure what you're doing, you should choose a good, well tested, robust library that provides such sanitization functions. [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) is the only one I know that fits this description.

Comment: Best of all available solutions. Was hesitant to answer this myself because they already seem to be accepting HTML and I didn't want to suggest the change. But if it's feasible to use another markup language - do it.

Comment: Thank you, the HTML Purifier seems like the best solution in this instance. As the ability to input data will be in a password protected area, and limited to very few users, I am happy for them to be able to input html.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can just strip `<script>` tags, using `strip_tags()` **this is not a bulletproof solution**, but you can improve the safety by just allowing some tags (basically bold, italics, links and a few more)...

You can then easily print your content and avoid javascript execution.

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p>, <a> and some formatting
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a><i><em><b><strong>');
```

Comment: `strip_tags` is not enough, as it doesn't remove attributes from elements. Consider `<a onmouseover="..."></a>`

Comment: Which part of **this is not a bulletproof solution** did you miss? :)

Comment: You mentioned that you can "improve the safety by just allowing some tags" which isn't really true. You don't really improve safety at all by implementing a whitelist of allowed tags. You also mentioned you can "avoid javascript execution" which you can't with this method. Just for a side note: downvote wasn't from me. Don't be upset. I'm just suggesting improvement.

Comment: +1 as I found this answer helped me build a better understanding of the overall subject, and you did make it clear that it wasn't a perfect solution.